# "normalize" dataframe of sentences into larger dataframe of words

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using Python and Spark:

Assuming I have a DataFrame with rows containing sentences, how can I `normalize` (from DBMS terms) the sentence DataFrame into another DataFrame with each row containing a word split out of the sentence?

I think this is mostly the [telegraph problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming#.22Telegram_Problem.22).

For instance, assume `df_sentences` looks like this:

```
[Row(sentence_id=1, sentence=u'the dog ran the fastest.'),
 Row(sentence_id=2, sentence=u'the cat sat down.')]
```

I am looking for the transformation `df_sentences` into `df_words` that will take these two rows and build a larger (in row count) DataFrame such as below.  Notice the sentence_id is carried across into the new table:

```
[Row(sentence_id=1, word=u'the'),
 Row(sentence_id=1, word=u'the'),
 Row(sentence_id=1, word=u'fastest'), 
 Row(sentence_id=2, word=u'dog'),
 Row(sentence_id=2, word=u'ran'), 
 Row(sentence_id=2, word=u'cat'), 
 ...clip...]
```

Now, at the moment I'm not really interested in row counts, or unique words, and that is because I want join to other RDD's on `sentence_id` to get other interesting data I have stored elsewhere.

I suspect much of being capable in spark resides around these intermittent transformation in pipelines so I want to have an understanding of the best way to do things and begin collecting my own snippets/etc.

Comment: Following the documentation here - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html I think you can use `flatMap`, get a new RDD and create a new data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually pretty simple. Lets start with creating a `DataFrame`:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = sc.parallelize([
    Row(sentence_id=1, sentence=u'the dog ran the fastest.'),
     Row(sentence_id=2, sentence=u'the cat sat down.')
]).toDF()
```

Next we'll need a tokenizer:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import RegexTokenizer

tokenizer = RegexTokenizer(
    inputCol="sentence", outputCol="words", pattern="\\W+")
tokenized = tokenizer.transform(df)
```

Finally we drop `sentence` and `explode` `words`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col

transformed = (tokenized
    .drop("sentence")
    .select(col("sentence_id"), explode(col("words")).alias("word")))
```

Finally the result:

```
transformed.show()

## +-----------+-------+
## |sentence_id|   word|
## +-----------+-------+
## |          1|    the|
## |          1|    dog|
## |          1|    ran|
## |          1|    the|
## |          1|fastest|
## |          2|    the|
## |          2|    cat|
## |          2|    sat|
## |          2|   down|
## +-----------+-------+
```

**Notes**:

- depending on a data `explode` can be rather expensive since it replicates other columns. Be sure to apply all the filters you can before applying `explode`, for example with `StopWordsRemover`